# How to position an element using skrollr.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the following [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEBEEg) I would like the phone to stick to the page and I want the two (contents)divs that I have to scroll from bottom to the top and then stick there.

I am using this library [scrollr.js](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) but I cannott get what I want.

**I want the phone to be fixed in the second section, and on scroll content one and content two will appear one by one and stick to the top.**

Here I have the content code:

```
 <div class="explanation" data-300="opacity: 0" data-350="opacity: 1">
  <h2>First Content</h2>
    <p>Play at home, while you eat, while you poop, and while you walk. Actually, better to look at the street while you walk.</p>
    <a class="arrow" href="#anchor2"><i class="icon-sort-down"></i></a>
    </div><!--/ explanation-->
    <div class="explanation2" data-350="opacity: 0" data-400="opacity: 1">
  <h2>Second Content</h2>
    <p>Second Content Second Content.</p>
    <a class="arrow" href="#anchor2"><i class="icon-sort-down"></i></a>
    </div><!--/ explanation-->
  </div>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: where is the HTML for your phone?

Comment: You can check the codepen

Comment: Try making your phone `<div id="phone" />` `position: fixed;` and manipulating it that way. I might be off base with exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but you may need to detach that element from your `sect1` div as well.